# how to print using printToPrinter serially programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to print records programmatically one by one. The next print should wait to complete the previous print. here is the code,

**Updated the code:**

```
-(void)GetOrdersHanlder:(id)object
{
        NSArray *ordersArray = (NSArray *)object;

        for (int i = 0; i < ordersArray.count;i++) {
            ITsOrder *orderObject = [ordersArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [ordersMutableArray addObject:orderObject];
        }

        if (ordersMutableArray.count > 0) {
            [self printOrder:[self getHtmlPrintStringForOrderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]] orderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
}

-(void)printOrder:(NSString*)htmlPrintString orderObject:(ITsOrder*)orderObject{

    //    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    printInteractionController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printInteractionController.delegate = self;
    printInteractionController.showsPageRange = YES;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"InvoicePrint";
    printInteractionController.printInfo = printInfo;

    htmlFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                     initWithMarkupText:htmlPrintString];
    htmlFormatter.startPage = 0;
    printInteractionController.printFormatter = htmlFormatter;

    [logsMutableString appendFormat:@"\n\nPrint Started: Order No #%d",orderObject.order_no];
    logsTextView.text = logsMutableString;

    [printInteractionController printToPrinter:savedPrinter
                             completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
                                 if(!completed && error){
                                     NSLog( @"Printing failed due to error in domain %@ with error code %lu. Localized description: %@, and failure reason: %@", error.domain, (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason );

                                     [logsMutableString appendFormat:@"\nPrint Failed: Order No #%d",orderObject.order_no];
                                     logsTextView.text = logsMutableString;
                                 }else{
                                     [logsMutableString appendFormat:@"\nPrint Successful: Order No #%d",orderObject.order_no];
                                     logsTextView.text = logsMutableString;
                                 }

                                 [ordersMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                                 if (ordersMutableArray.count > 0 ) {
                                     [self printOrder:[self getHtmlPrintStringForOrderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]] orderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]];
                                 }

                             }];

    //    });
}
```

--

I updated the code, calling , [self printOrder:[self getHtmlPrintStringForOrderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]] orderObject:[ordersMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]];,  in completion handler but got the following output,

```
Print Started: Order No #114
Print Successful: Order No #114

Print Started: Order No #116
```

there are 4 objects in array. but looks like, printToPrinter is not executing next time.

Comment: Rather than dispatching all of the print operations at once you should use the completion block from the printInteractionController to see if there is more work to be done and dispatch the next print operation from there

Comment: @Paulw11, I updated the code, and did what you said. but the next print operation is not working.

Comment: Check which queue executes the completion handler - perhaps try dispatching the call to `printOrder` within the completion block on the main queue.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11, its working now .. :)